# Keep Bootstrap 2.3.2 dropdown menu open while opening a modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I know there are some posts around discussing how to keep a Bootstrap menu open when clicked, but my scenario is a bit different, and I can't find a working solution yet.

What I need is: to keep the dropdown menu open when an item in that menu is clicked to show a modal. My markup looks like this:

```
<!-- dropdown -->
<ul>
    <li class="createTag">
        <a class="createTagA" href="#tagInfoModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Create New</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- modal -->
<div id="tagInfoModal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header header-blue">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Tag Info</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="box-content">
            <form action="#" method="POST" class='form-horizontal form-validate' id="tagInfoForm" data-bind="submit: saveTag">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="nameOfTag" class="control-label">Tag *</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="nameOfTag" id="nameOfTag" class="input-xlarge">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="createNewTag();">Save Tag</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The plan here is when the createTag anchor in the dropdown menu is clicked, the modal shows up. What is more, I want the dropdown menu to stay open while the modal is up, and to stay open while the modal is closed too. The default behavior is the dropdown menu goes away when the modal is open, which is not what I want.

I have tried returning false/stop propagation in the anchor's click event handler as suggested in some online answers, while the menu is kept open this way, it breaks the modal -- the modal does not show up anymore.

So my effort to prevent the dropdown menu from being closed is like this:

```
$(".createTagA").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

I am not familiar with Bootstrap. Can anyone give me some hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your javascript? Or even better make a jsfiddle as well?

Comment: Sure. Javascript snippet added. As to jsfiddle, I need to figure out the howtos and might add that later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using javascript instead of html to open the modal, and stoping the propagation of the click event.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/669/)

*Javascript*

```
$(".createTagA").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#tagInfoModal").modal('show');        
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="createTag">
        <a class="createTagA" role="button">Create New</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- modal -->
<div id="tagInfoModal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header header-blue">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Tag Info</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="box-content">
            <form action="#" method="POST" class='form-horizontal form-validate' id="tagInfoForm" data-bind="submit: saveTag">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="nameOfTag" class="control-label">Tag *</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="nameOfTag" id="nameOfTag" class="input-xlarge" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="createNewTag();">Save Tag</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The menu is still open when the modal is shown, but when the modal is closed, the menu is closed too. I'm not sure it's the behavior you want.

Comment: Nice and simple! Thanks for this quick solution. And yes, we still need the menu to stay open when the modal is closed. Any further comment on how to keep it open after the modal is closed?

Comment: I've found a solution for Bootstrap 3 (http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/ZS4L7/), but not for Bootstrap 2.3.2. The events shown.bs.dropdown and hide.bs.dropdown are not fired in 2.3.2. I'll try to adapt that.

Comment: It's great to hear that you got it working with Bootstrap 3! Although we are looking to upgrade to Bootstrap 3 later, 2.3.2 is the version we have invested quite a bit of dev/QA time in. So I think we will have to live with 2.3.2 as our deadline is nearing.

And I tried both events shown.bs.dropdown and hide.bs.dropdown as well, just like you said, they were not fired in 2.3.2.